# How to execute a .Bat with mutliple Parameters from Powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, parameters, batch-file

how do I execue a .bat from a powershell script.

I want to do something like:

```
foreach($item in $list){

  param1= $item.Name
  param2= $item.path

  C:\Filesystem_Batches\test.bat param1 param2

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can call

```
cmd.exe /C "test.bat param1 param2"
```

In powershell V3 there is a new espace string --% which allow to send "weird" parameters to your exes.
exemple :

```
PS> echoargs.exe --% %USERNAME%,this=$something{weird} 

Arg 0 is <jason,this=$something{weird}>
```

Comment: If the path or filename for the .bat or .cmd file contains one or more spaces, wrap the path in escaped (escape char is the backtick in PowerShell) double quotes, or use a combination of single and double quotes:

    cmd.exe /C "`"test file.bat`" param1 param2"
    cmd.exe /C '"test file.bat" param1 param2'

Answer (score 6):

I am new to Powershell but the following works for me. I am able to run the `*.bat` from my `*.ps1` file. And I am using Powershell 5.1.17134.590.

```
& .\myFile.bat parm1
```